# How do I deploy spring-boot WAR to Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, war

I have spent a good number of hours on this before posting...

I have a spring-boot application that runs nicely as a JAR, but when I try to convert it to a WAR I cant deploy it.

I have tried looking for the rules for it to decide whether it Tomcat is embedded or external.

The WAR looks correct with WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/lib-provided with no obviously misplaced jars.

My Application class extends SpringBootServletInitializer. When debugging, this class sets the application context class to AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.class... is this correct?

Should I expect to see *Embedded* classes being loaded when trying to deploy as a WAR?

I am using :-

1) spring framework 4.1.2.RELEASE
2) spring-boot 1.1.9.RELEASE
3) spring security 3.2.5.RELEASE
4) Tomcat 7.0.57

The application uses both WebMvc and WebSockets...

Regards

My parent POM has

```
<dependencyManagement>
    ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencyManagement>
```

My POM contains the following spring-boot artifacts.

```
    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        <!-- WebSocket Latest -->
        <!--<version>1.2.0.RC1</version>-->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This is deploying inside Tomcat 7.0.57 as a WAR with -Ddebug

Sorry for so much logging ;-(

```
....
123143 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yaml' for profile resource not found
123143 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@54d9aaa1: startup date [Wed Dec 03 09:13:08 GMT 2014]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c6debf9
123190 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@54d9aaa1: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@10dbb363: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,play.application,errorPageFilter]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3d5e51e5
141940 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/E:/Software/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/cf_shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring/beanRefContext.xml]
142065 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/E:/Software/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/cf_shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring/globalApplicationContext.xml]
142174 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/E:/Software/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/cf_shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring/globalApplicationContext-configuration.xml]
142455 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages$BasePackages]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
146518 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
162564 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'async' of type [class com.cf.play.config.Async$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd119135] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
162939 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService  'getAsyncExecutor'
162939 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'getAsyncExecutor' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
162939 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7617ce05] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
164892 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c9aa01e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
165611 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
165642 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@41b21e0a' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
167330 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'security.AuthenticationConfiguration' of type [class com.cf.play.config.Security$AuthenticationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f014df73] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
168111 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe30e14e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
169814 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'securityProperties' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
170861 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$538cd08c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
171392 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/E:/Software/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/cf_shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring/globalApplicationContext-configuration.xml]
171502 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/E:/Software/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/cf_shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring/globalApplicationContext-security.xml]
171908 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.s.c.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.5.RELEASE
171939 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.s.c.SecurityNamespaceHandler - Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.5.RELEASE
172267 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/E:/Software/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/cf_shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring/globalApplicationContext.xml]
172377 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@7b50e9c5: startup date [Wed Dec 03 09:13:57 GMT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
172705 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.e.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean - Initializing EhCache CacheManager
174923 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
175048 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
175048 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
175064 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
175064 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'CAS ProxyGrantingTicketStorage Scheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

175064 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'CAS ProxyGrantingTicketStorage Scheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
175064 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
175080 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@24917741
175111 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
175111 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
175111 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler CAS ProxyGrantingTicketStorage Scheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
175330 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'globalParentApplicationContext' of type [class org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
175392 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61dc3bd3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
176486 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4cff750] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
176658 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
176736 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
176767 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@10a32452]
176783 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Using ApplicationEventMulticaster [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@774aa541]
323644 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory - Code archive: E:\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar
323644 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory - Code archive: E:\Software\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar
323644 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory - None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
323660 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory - Server initialized with port: 8080
Dec 03, 2014 9:16:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Dec 03, 2014 9:16:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Dec 03, 2014 9:16:29 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader startInternal
SEVERE: LifecycleException 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:582)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5357)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have a web.xml and if you have it either remove it or at least make sure the version is 3.0 and not lower. Post some configuration and your pom. As it looks to me you are overriding the default Spring Boot dependencies instead of using the starters (which is recommended). Spring boot 1.1.x uses Spring 4.0 if I recall correctly.

Comment: The starter-web dependency shouldn't be marked as provided. It's just starter-tomcat that requires that.

Comment: I have removed the 'provided' scope from the starter-web dependency. The results are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found the problem....Configuration!

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application
            .showBanner(true)
            .parent(Global.class)
            .child(applicationClass)
            .profiles("container")
            ;
}
```

should be ...

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application
            .showBanner(true)
            .parent(Global.class)
            .sources(applicationClass)
            .profiles("container")
            ;
}
```

... I used child() instead of sources()...

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you can accept your own answer to show others that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make your parent spring-boot-starter-parent?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Also you should make spring-boot-starter-tomcat provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If you link your whole POM or effective POM that may help

Comment: I can't make the parent Pom the boot parent as I already use an internal hierarchy and the scope for that artefact is already set to provided as above... My WAR file looks correct. What is the rule for boot choosing embedded over external?

Comment: The main decision point is based on whether or not there's a ServletContext. If there isn't, Boot will start an embedded container.

Comment: I have updated the question with the log output. The odd thing is that it thinks it should start the embedded tomcat when it is clearly a WAR being loaded by Tomcat. I would assume that I should not see any classes with the word 'Embed' in their classname in this case...

Comment: Debugging the code, I find that there is NO servletContext and therefore an embeddedServletContainer is created. The catalina servletContext is available to the SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup() but seems to either be lost or not passed on...