# Web.xml still missing when deploying a Spring Boot RESTful Web Service to Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, gradle, tomcat7, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a RESTful Web Service built with Spring Boot into a Tomcat instance, with little success.

My software configuration is as follows: my computer is a Mac running `OS X Yosemite 10.10.3`, with `Oracle Java JDK 8 1.8.0_45`, `Gradle 2.4` and `Apache Tomcat 7.0.47`. I use `IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4` as development platform.

I started by following this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and I got a jar that initiates an embedded container which works as expected. Then I followed the document about `converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR` linked at the end of the other [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/). I followed the instructions in `Section 59.4 "Packaging executable jar and war files"` and then those in the `Section 74.1 "Create a deployable war file"`. According to the posts of a few other members of this site who were facing the same problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741816/deploy-spring-boot-to-tomcat), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256904/how-do-i-deploy-spring-boot-war-to-tomcat), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623468/spring-boot-war-deployment-to-tomcat-with-statusok-but-gives-404-on-access) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884010/gradle-spring-boot-project-not-working-in-tomcat-as-a-war), just to name a few), I should be able now to create a create a WAR and deploy it on my Tomcat. Unfortunately, this is not the case.

The project contains the following 3 Java files: `Application.java`, `Greeting.java` and `GreetingController.java`. The first is as follows:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

The second file contains the following:

```
package hello;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;

    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

}
```

And, finally, the latter file is:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

The project also contains the following build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

war {
    baseName = 'rest'
//    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Now, if I run the task "gradle war", I generate a WAR file of about 8 Mb. I can successfully deploy it to my local Tomcat, but when I point my browser to http://localhost:8080/rest/hello?name=World I got a blank page rather than the page with the expected JSON. If I run the task "gradle build" or "gradle bootRepackage", I get both a JAR and a WAR and their original versions. I'm mentioning these commands because I haven't seen them anywhere and they might be useful to know. The original versions are both around 8 Mb in size, while the JAR and the WAR of 12 Mb. If I deploy both WARs, I get no error messages but, again, no results in the browser. Somebody here suggested that the web.xml could be missing, and in fact no WAR actually contained such a file. I am saying so because my Tomcat is not very recent and for some reason I thought Spring Boot had to automatically create a `web.xml` out of the code and annotations above.

As suggested by @dunni in the comments, here are my Tomcat log files. First of all, `catalina.log`:

```
giu 24, 2015 10:35:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest.war
```

Then `localhost.log`:

```
giu 24, 2015 10:35:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@4dfaba52]
```

And finally `manager.log`:

```
giu 24, 2015 10:34:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
giu 24, 2015 10:34:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
giu 24, 2015 10:35:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

The above content is what I get after deploy the WAR. Nothing changes if I subsequently try to connect to http://localhost:8080/, http://localhost:8080/rest/, http://localhost:8080/rest/hello or http://localhost:8080/rest/hello?name=World.

What is going on? What am I missing? Can you please explain me what is the problem and what have I to do to successfully deploy this toy service on Tomcat? Many thanks in advance.

---

Since the above logs were not really helpful, I tried to restart the Tomcat daemon and I got something more meaningful. Now I have the following files: `catalina.log`, `catalina.out`, `host-manager.log` (empty), `launchd.stderr` (empty), `launchd.stdout`, `localhost_access_log.txt` (empty), `localhost.log` and `manager.log` (empty). `catalina.log` and `catalina.out` now contains the following:

```
giu 24, 2015 11:11:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/stefano/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
giu 24, 2015 11:11:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
giu 24, 2015 11:11:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
giu 24, 2015 11:11:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 666 ms
giu 24, 2015 11:11:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
giu 24, 2015 11:11:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
giu 24, 2015 11:11:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/Plakko.war
giu 24, 2015 11:11:51 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [574] milliseconds.
giu 24, 2015 11:11:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest.war
giu 24, 2015 11:11:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/docs
giu 24, 2015 11:11:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/host-manager
giu 24, 2015 11:11:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/manager
giu 24, 2015 11:11:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/ROOT
giu 24, 2015 11:11:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
giu 24, 2015 11:11:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
giu 24, 2015 11:11:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3349 ms
```

`launchd.stdout` contains:

```
Wed Jun 24 11:11:48 CEST 2015
Starting Tomcat
Waiting for 89105
```

And `localhost.log` contains:

```
giu 24, 2015 11:11:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@2d5eb959]
```

If I try to consume the Web Service, `localhost_access_log.txt` is updated with:

```
217.20.22.194 - - [24/Jun/2015:11:23:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11444
217.20.22.194 - - [24/Jun/2015:11:23:19 +0200] "GET /rest/ HTTP/1.1" 404 5
217.20.22.194 - - [24/Jun/2015:11:23:19 +0200] "GET /rest/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 5
217.20.22.194 - - [24/Jun/2015:11:23:20 +0200] "GET /rest/hello?name=World HTTP/1.1" 404 5
```

---

Since I have the feeling that these logs are not really helpful, I tried to shutdown and startup Tomcat. In this case I find something interesting in `catalina.log` and `catalina.out`. The former:

```
giu 24, 2015 11:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest.war
giu 24, 2015 11:36:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rest]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()Z
    at org.springframework.core.StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getFromFactory(BeanTypeRegistry.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.get(BeanTypeRegistry.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

giu 24, 2015 11:36:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rest]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And the latter `catalina.out`:

```
giu 24, 2015 11:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest.war

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.4.RELEASE)

2015-06-24 11:36:59.019  INFO 89274 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on Mac-mini-di-Stefano.local with PID 89274 (/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar started by stefano in /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin)
2015-06-24 11:36:59.047  INFO 89274 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@34a13c2b: startup date [Wed Jun 24 11:36:59 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-06-24 11:36:59.648  INFO 89274 --- [ost-startStop-1] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/rest/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar]
2015-06-24 11:36:59.663 ERROR 89274 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()Z
    at org.springframework.core.StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getFromFactory(BeanTypeRegistry.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.get(BeanTypeRegistry.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

By looking at these logs, I have the feeling that something is failing in the auto-magical process of Spring but unfortunately I don't know what and how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: You don't need a web.xml in a Servlet-3.0-compatible application. The SpringBootServletInitializer does the work. Also are there any log messages in the tomcat logfile?

Comment: @dunni Thanks for the reply, I assumed I needed a `web.xml` (and that Spring Boot was generating one out of the Java code and annotations in the project) because my Tomcat is not very recent. Thanks for suggesting to have a look at the log files (which I'm going to add to my question, by the way): I should not post anything late in the night, or I'll miss trivial things like these.

Comment: I updated my Tomcat to the latest 8 version (8.0.23) but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

What version of java are you using?  The gradle file indicates you intend to use java 8, but this error indicates you are not...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()
```

[The Parameter class was not introduced until java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html).  What version of java is your tomcat using?

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I followed [this guide](https://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/tomcat8/) to install my Tomcat on my Yosemite. I think it's using the latest Java (at the time of writing this message) which is Oracle Java 8 u 45. In practice, if I invoke `java -version` in a Terminal, I get the following: `java version "1.8.0_45"` `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)` `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)`. The other services running there were created with Java 7, though. What else can I check?

Comment: I've found a page suggesting to open a Terminal, `cd` to the Tomcat install folder and run `java -cp lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo` to determine the version of either Tomcat and Java. Here is the resulting output: `Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23` `Server built:   May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC` `Server number:  8.0.23.0` `OS Name:        Mac OS X` `OS Version:     10.10.3` `Architecture:   x86_64` `JVM Version:    1.8.0_45-b14` `JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation`.